# angular2 NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Angular2 rc.6

I am getting following error when running a loop on json data

core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Error in app/modules/mbs/components/menu.html:5:4 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

my html loop, **Note**: I simply want to iterate properties and arrays inside the response.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
{{item}}
</li>
```

my service method

```
getMenuItems():Promise<any>{
    return this.http.get('api/menu').toPromise().
    then(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)

}
```

following is my json response

```
{  
"text":"Menu",
   "children":[
      {
         "text":"Home",
         "url":"/spatt-web/home"
      },
      {
         "text":"Configure",
         "children":[
            {
               "text":"Tri-Party Program",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "text":"Margins and Filters",
                     "url":"/sp-rrp/config/operation"
                  },
                  {
                     "text":"Fields and Desirability",
                     "url":"/spatt-rrp/config/program"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "text":"Shared Settings",
               "url":"/shared-config/config"
            },
            {
               "text":"SOMA Limits",
               "url":"/outright-config/config"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"Plan",
         "children":[
            {
               "text":"Tri-Party RRP Operations",
               "url":"/spatt-rrp/plan"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "text":"Track"
      },
      {
         "text":"Administer"
      },
      {
         "text":"Help",
         "children":[
            {
               "text":"RRP Operations",
               "url":"RRPference"
            },
            {
               "text":"RRP Margin Calls and Recalls",
               "url":"RRPRecallference"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: And what is the result you expect?

Comment: What is it that you want to display? As the error demonstrates, you cannot simply use NgFor to loop through members in an object. There are ways to fix it but I need to understand what you're trying to do first

Comment: thanks for comment. i simply want to display properties and iterate through children array

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menuItems.children">
{{item}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped me with my angular 5 app while using the deezer api.

Answer (score 11):

in case you are trying to iterate on an object:

```
  <div *ngFor="let location of locations | keyvalue">
       {{location.key}} - {{location.value | json}}
  </div>
```

[KeyValuePipe Documntation](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Comment: This helped me iterate over Template Driven Form Validation Errors.

Comment: This `keyvalue`  is really nice... living and learning! :D

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the error means you are trying to iterate on an object instead of array or observable.